# Chrome Extension: How can I get global settings in preference

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As you know that there are many entries in chrome://settings, is there any way that I can read the value in my extension JS code? e.g. get the "homepage", "account_info" etc.

The values present in the file names Preferences which locates in folder Google\Chrome\User Data\Default.

Thanks.
Easton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marco's answer stating you can't access settings is not entirely true.

[Chrome APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) provide access to some settings:

- [accessibility](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/accessibilityFeatures),
- [privacy settings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/privacy),
- [font settings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/fontSettings),
- [content settings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings),

and maybe the [identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity) can read account info.

Homepage, though, is not directly accessible, as are many other settings. It is correct that this is done for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you Xan and Macro, Yes, security can be the consideration for account info.

Comment: weird that [you can *write* the homepage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/settings_override/), but not *read* it—especially considering the latter has [actual legitimate utility](https://github.com/cadeyrn/newtaboverride/blob/df37fe3a7b6de11b7232a6189a1b0784bca3d496/src/js/core/newtab.js#L34) while the former is nothing but a receptacle for sales/ad/referral funnel injections