# Is there a JS Browser API to check for cookie auto delete?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a JS Browser API to check if a browser has cookie auto-deletion active upon closing the browser or after x days?

Comment: I doubt it does

Comment: I suspect not. In general, I don't think there are APIs to access most browser preferences.

Comment: Maybe it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979202/chrome-extension-how-can-i-get-global-settings-in-preference can help you